# turn off autocomplete for HTML elements in Developer Console

Tags: developer-console

Is it possible to turn off the autocomplete for HTML elements in Developer Console?

I tried turning off Apex Auto-complete but that didn't help.

[image: developer console prefs]

It's incredibly frustrating when every element I put on the page is auto closed and put two lines below.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible to turn it off from the preferences or anywhere else in the UI. It should be able to be turned off though. I would file an idea on the idea exchange to add more options to the preferences.

If you wanted a (hacky) workaround, I created a bookmarklet you can use to disable the tag auto close on existing VF editors, and all plugins on new editors. If you still want things like gutter folding and matching tags on new editors, let me know and I can update the gist.

https://gist.github.com/amphro/0138a58e3df0ca210b30

To use a bookmarklet, copy the code in the gist, add a new bookmark in you browser and paste the code as the URL. Then open the developer console in a **tab** so you access the bookmark. When the dev console loads, press the bookmark and the auto close tags should be disabled. Let me know if you have trouble with it. *I only tested it in chrome.*

Comment: wow, very cool.  I only use Firefox, but I will see how it does!

Comment: The bookmarklet should work in FF too. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: I finally got around to trying this, and I don't think I did the bookmarlet right.  I pasted all of the code ( including the javascript: ) into the location for the tab, but it goes to a page with some JS on it when I click it.

Comment: Yo can't put it in the location of the tab (the address bar). I believe it only works if you add it as a bookmark, go to the developer console in a tab, then click on the bookmark.